# Header for My Tutorial

Tags: tables, pdftex

I am new to LaTeX and new to this website also. I need to create front page header for my tutorials.(see the attached image).

This is not header for all pages. this is for front page header.

Can anyone give me idea to create this front page header ?

Which latex template package should I use ?

any sample code or website link ?

[image]

I need to create above header for my class tutorials.

Help me !!!

Answer (score 2):

Only a first trial, due to lack of time --fill in the rest of information

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.45\textwidth}|@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\large \bfseries Chintaka Mandura \tabularnewline
Bsc.Eng(Hons), University of Peradeniya \tabularnewline
English \tabularnewline
Tel. \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{p{0.3\textwidth}|X}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Name: \dotfill} \tabularnewline[1.5ex]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{School: \dotfill} \tabularnewline[1.5ex]
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\hline
Grad 09: Pure further Mathematics & Tute No: \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx} \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christian..  I am new to this website. therefore i can not tumb up your answer. if i have this permission, i will definitely accept and tumb  up your answer.

you save my lot of time.

Comment: @chinthaka Accepting is possible after some period, upvoting only if you have a reputation higher than 10 (I believe)